# 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'a' Error

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a list of all tags and I keep getting this error. The html code looks like this:

What am I missing?
[image]

```
tags=[]

df2= pd.DataFrame(columns =['post'], data= lists2)
for y in range(0,26):
    post=( df2.post.iloc[y])
    url_post = urllib.request.urlopen(post).read()
    soup2= bs.BeautifulSoup(url_post,'lxml')
    tag= soup2.find_all('div',class_="thread-tags").a.get_text().strip()
    tags.append(tag)
```

Comment: The `div` you are looking for is most likely generated by javascript, `urllib.request` is only responsible for getting source from original url, so the content you are looking for is not there.

Comment: Please include your actual code, and not screenshots of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was

```
tags=[]

df2= pd.DataFrame(columns =['post'], data= lists2)
for y in range(0,2340):
    post=( df2.post.iloc[y])
    url_post = urllib.request.urlopen(post).read()
    soup2= bs.BeautifulSoup(url_post,'lxml')
    tag= soup2.find_all('div',class_="thread-tags")[0].get_text().strip()
    tags.append(tag)
```